# replacing null values in the whole dataframe based on values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
a   b    c    d
1   NaN  1    2
NaN  1   3    4
3    NaN NaN  5
```

I need to replace the null values in each row based on the value of `column d`.

The output should be:

```
a   b    c    d
1   2    1    2
4   1    3    4
3   5    5    5
```

I tried this followings, but none of them worked:

```
df.fillna(df.d, inplace= True)
df.iloc[:].fillna(df.d, inplace= True)
df.replace(np.NaN, df.d, inplace=True)
```

I have too many columns, so I cannot use column by column to fill the null values. 
How can I fill in the null values in all columns at once using the values in column d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a clone `df1` from `df` with values all broadcast from `df.d`. Next, use it to fillna `df`

```
df1 = df[['d']].reindex(columns=df.columns).bfill(1)
df.fillna(df1)

Out[153]:
     a    b    c  d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2
1  4.0  1.0  3.0  4
2  3.0  5.0  5.0  5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way `combine_first`

```
df=df.combine_first(df.fillna(0).add(df.d,0))
df
     a    b    c  d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2
1  4.0  1.0  3.0  4
2  3.0  5.0  5.0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use loop to replace all :

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col !='d':
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[1,np.nan,3],'b':[np.nan, 1, np.nan], 'c':[1,3,np.nan], 'd': [2,4,5]})

for col in df: 
    df.loc[df[col].isnull(), col] = df['d']

#      a    b    c  d
# 0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2
# 1  4.0  1.0  3.0  4
# 2  3.0  5.0  5.0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, np.nan, 1, 2], [np.nan, 1, 3, 4], [3, np.nan, np.nan, 5]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# Iterate over all columns and replace null values with value in column d
for column in df:
    df.loc[(pd.isnull(df[column])), column] = df.d
```